# restore mysqldump in php script

Tags: php, mysql, restore

I have created a back up dump file with mysqldump. Now, I need to restore the file back. Below is my script:

```
<?php

$dbhost   = "localhost";
$dbuser   = "root";
$dbpwd    = "";
$dbname   = "fhc";
$dumpfile = 'backup/fhc_2013-10-11_04-30-20.sql';

exec("C://xampp/mysql/bin/mysql --opt --host=$dbhost --user=$dbuser --password=$dbpwd $dbname < $dumpfile");

?>
```

Is there anything wrong with the script? i couldn't get the file restored into my database.

Comment: You should try `file_get_contents()` on your dump file, then put the lot into a standard mysql query. If whatever you used to dump your DB did it in a syntactically correct way, the whole thing should execute fine with `mysqli_query` or similar.

Comment: What error did you got?

Comment: @RafaelBarros no error is given...just that the contents that I have deleted previously...I cant get it back after running the script above.

Comment: @scrowler i have run the file_get_contents()..the contents are correctly the tables that I'm working on... how can I check if the file is been executed or not? any return value for exec() ?

Comment: Read the manual dude: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php
Again, if your dump was created by a correct way, it should have `create table if not exists` etc so it shouldn't matter

Comment: so basically r u saying that there is no problem with the script?

Comment: I'm saying put your query dump into standard PHP MySQL query functions.